# Custom method on class that conforms to MKAnnotation protocol

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation

I have a class:

```
class MyAnnotion: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

let title: String?
let subtitle: String?
let item: MyCustomItem
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(customItem: MyCustomItem, currentLocation: CLLocation)  {
    coordinate = item.coordinate
    pageId = "\(item.pageId)"
    title = "\(item.title)"
    item = myCustomItem
}

//TODO: Even though in mapView viewFor: the annotation is a WikiAnnotation, it wont recognize any custom function defined here
func imageUrl() -> String? {
    guard let url = item.imageUrl else {
        return nil
    }
    return url
}
}
```

When I load my annotations into the map, I load them as `MyAnnotion`s.

The `mapView viewFor:` function passes an `MKAnnotation` annotation but when I check it's actually a `MyAnnotation`.

Trouble is, if I try to access the imageUrl() method it tells me that MKAnnotation doesn't have that method.

I've tried all sorts of silly things like casting it as my custom annotation and making an extension on MKAnnotation.

Any ideas how to grab the imageUrl from that custom class?

Thanks!

Comment: You . have to cast as your needed class MyAnnotion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need cast to your custom annotation class, as I said in my comments,

**this is the code**

```
func mapView(_ map: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if let customAnnotation = annotation as? MyAnnotion{
           let imageUrl = customAnnotation.imageUrl()
        }
}
```

Comment: Yep.  I've been working in Java for a while and my casting syntax was all wrong.  Thanks!  I suppose I should sleep ...

Comment: Your welcome @MayNotBe remember is always better use conditional casting because force cast can cause crashes

Comment: Thought I did. Sleeping now. Thanks

Comment: My annotation type is `CustomPointAnnotation`, I tried to downcast the annotation to `CustomPointAnnotation`. Some annotations(created in Frameworks' target) are casted properly to `CustomPointAnnotation` but one annotation(called PickupAnnotation) is not down casting to `CustomPointAnnotation`. But if I check that annotation type then it's the `CustomAnnotationType`. I created that pickup annotation from another target(ExampleProject) and passing it into framework's class(FrameworkTarget). In this class only I'm handling the map view delegates. Can you please help me ? @ReinierMelian

Answer (score 0):

You need to force cast to `MyAnnotation`, like this:

```
(annotation as! MyAnnotation).imageUrl()
```

Comment: Thanks, but Reinier beat you by 3 min.

Comment: Ah, well. It hadn't loaded on my machine when I had posted it, so I posted my answer, too